# Change Database-Name/Server at runtime

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ado.net

I am using Visual Studios build-in DataSource functions, to work with my application and its database. Now I am facing one little problem; How do I change the database-server in the final project?

Obviously the end-users server name will not be the same as mine.

Also how can I change it at runtime? My application has functions to find the database-server itself, so it needs to be able to change the database server at runtime (Only at applcations start) .

**Update 1:**
Right now I am Changing my `TableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString` with `.Replace("My Local Server Name", "New Server Name")` to change the Server. But I don't think that's the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: aren't you using any connectionstrings?

Comment: I am, but those are stored in my.settings by VisualStudio. Those are readonly at runtime.

Comment: Use a configuration file and a static class?

Comment: You should change the scope to "user" settings, that way the connectionstring will be in the app.config

Comment: Seems like you haven't worked with Visual Studios DataSource functions very much. Just like me. You can not change the scope since the IDE created it and manages it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the connection string after deployment then you edit the config file by hand or you can do so in code if the current user is an administrator.

If you want to change the connection string for a table adapter at run time to something other than what's in the config file then you do indeed need to set the `Connection.ConnectionString` property.  The most advisable way to do that is to use a connection string builder.  For an Access database, that might look like this:

```
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(myTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString)

builder.DataSource = dataSourceName
myTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid config files, because i do not want to write or edit them each time I install my app on a customers system. Specially when I know that my application can find the server name programmatically without me having to find out. Thanks for your answer and the connectionstringbuilder tip.

Comment: Did you specify that the connection string for your Data Source be stored in the config file when you created it?  If you don't want a config file then you should have said "no" to that.  Once you've said "yes", I'm not sure that you can avoid having a config file.  You could always test deleting it and see though.

Comment: The problem is not to have a configuration file. I am fine with that since it allows me to change settings if needed. But I don't want to must edit a configuration file each time I install the application. This way my application finds database servers on its own. I only have to go into configuration files, when the user needs specific changes.