# How do i change SQL database NAME in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio

I changed the name to fish the old database comes back, when I look in App_data folder in file explorer I find the old database named food. So the website is using the old database. Also I've change the name in web.config.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Database-Name/Server at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584439/change-database-name-server-at-runtime)

Comment: Hi, I've look at that answer but it did not help m.